# How to make sure component parameter is set with @bind-?

Tags: blazor, blazor-component

I've made a custom component which has a parameter. I've overridden `OnParametersSet` method to throw an exception if the parameter isn't set however I need to make sure the parameter uses two way bindings. If it is set as `MyParameter="somevalue"` it won't throw an exception and my event callback is not fired (I have MyParameterChanged event callback is defined). Is there a way to make sure this parameter is set as `@bind-MyParameter="somevalue"` so the child component notifies changes to the parent? I know there are other ways such as CascadingParameters (which couples it to the model) or custom event callbacks (then the parent page has to pass EvenCallback methods)

```
//parent
<mycustomcomponent @bind-MyParameter="parentModel.property" />

//child
<div><div/>
public List<string> MyParameter {get;set;}
[Parameter] public EventCallback<List<string>> MyParameterChanged { get; set; }
protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.OnParametersSet();

        if (myproperty is null)
            throw new ArgumentException("The 'MyParameter' property is not set", nameof(MyParameter));
    }
// some methods to modify MyParameter
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by checking if the EventCallback has a delegate:

`MyPropertyChanged.HasDelegate` returns false if the property is set as `MyProperty="somevalue"` instead of `@bind-MyProperty="somevalue"`

Replaced `if (MyProperty is null)` with `if (!MyPropertyChanged.HasDelegate)`